# How to get .aspx page from hosted application in IIS?

Tags: asp.net, iis-6

Is there any possible to get .aspx page from hosted application in IIS?

Any ideas?

Answer (score -1):

No you can't do that.

aspx is already interpreted by IIS.

The only way is to directly access the server.